# Can't insert into JDBC oracleRowSet buttonGroup

Tags: netbeans-8

```
private void Acc_Button_createActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

    int p = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, "Do you want add", "Add", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if (p == 0) {
        try {
            String sql = "insert into ACCOUNT_INFO  (ACC,NAMEF,DOB,PIN,ACCOUNT_TPAYE,NATIONALTY,CASTE,MICR_NO,GENDER,MOB_NO,ADDRESS,SEC_Q,SEC_A,BLANCE)values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            jrowSet.setCommand(sql);
            jrowSet.setString(1, Acc_TextField_acc.getText());
            jrowSet.setString(2, Acc_TextField_amunt.getText());
            jrowSet.setString(3, ((JTextField) Acc_DateChooser_birh.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
            jrowSet.setString(4, Acc_TextField_pin.getText());
            jrowSet.setString(5, (String) Acc_ComboBox_acc_type.getSelectedItem());
            jrowSet.setString(6, (String) Acc_ComboBox_naton.getSelectedItem());
            jrowSet.setString(7, Acc_TextField_name.getText());
            jrowSet.setString(8, Acc_TextField_misr.getText());
            // for radio btn
            RadioButton_male.setActionCommand("Male");
            RadioButton_female.setActionCommand("Femal");
            // to insert radin in database
            jrowSet.setString(9, buttonGroup2.getSelection().getActionCommand());
            jrowSet.setString(10, Acc_TextField_caste.getText());
            jrowSet.setString(11, Acc_TextField_adrres.getText());
            jrowSet.setString(12, (String) Acc_ComboBox_sq_q.getSelectedItem());
            jrowSet.setString(13, Acc_TextField_mob_no.getText());
            jrowSet.setString(14, Acc_TextField_seq_a.getText());
            jrowSet.execute();
          // Bal();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "added", "add acount", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        } catch (HeadlessException | SQLException e) {
        }
    }
}

// Acc_Button_createActionPerformed(Account.java:414) >> this is the ine 414 
 jrowSet.setString(9, buttonGroup2.getSelection().getActionCommand());
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: not working  this is the error  
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.mo7amd.Account.Acc_Button_createActionPerformed(Account.java:414)
and this is the line number 414 
jrowSet.setString(9, buttonGroup2.getSelection().getActionCommand());